# Django: foreign key (many-to-many) return empty queryset despite not being empty

Tags: django, many-to-many

My Model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
"""
An account is for a team of users, or a single customer
"""
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
admins = models.ManyToManyField('AccountUser', related_name='+', blank=True)
metadata = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

@property
def customers(self):
    """Accounts linked to this account"""
    return self.linked_accounts.linked_accounts.all()
```

and my code:

```
>>>account = Account.objects.get(id=1)
>>> print(account)
Bramble CFD
>>> print(account.name)
Bramble CFD
```

when I try to get the admins many_to_many field I get the following empty queryset:

```
>>> print(account.admins.all())
<QuerySet []>
```

but the admins field is not empty as demonstrate by the following screen shot from the django admin interface:

[image]

Comment: The `admins` field is empty for *that* `Account`: in the admin site you can use this widget to *select* what `Admin`s to add, but these are *not* added to the `Account`: likely *none* of the `Admins` is *selected* in the widget.

Comment: Forgive me, Williem. I don't understand your answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more? Thank you

Comment: There are admins, but none of these admins are linked to *that* `Account`.

Comment: Gosh, you are so right. I feel like an idiot, none is selected as admin. If you quickly turn your comment into an answer I will vote it. Thank you

Comment: I've found this question because I'm having the same issue, but in my case I'me pretty sure that I am selecting elements. Anybody has any idea of what I could be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `Admin`s, and your `Account` exists, but none of the `Admin`s are *linked* to *that* specific `Account`. The widget shows *all* `Admin`s.

You thus can link `Admin`s to an account by *selecting* these in the widget. In that case `account.admins.all()` will return the `Admin` objects selected for that account.